# jQuery : delete a page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using jQuery mobile and my page is generated from an index.php file. When I click on links referring to another option of my php file (index.php?action=other_action) it loads in Ajax so the previous content is still kept in the code. This causes problems as nothing is dynamic anymore, because I'm using specific ids, so it breaks everything. Of course disabling Ajax works but I loose all the beauty of jQuery Mobile.

I guess a solution would be to create an onclick function on the `<a>`, that will prevent the page from keeping the previous content or delete the old page.

So is there a way to keep using ajax in a way that it doesn't break my dynamic elements ?

You can see it in action [here](https://partyneverends.noho.st/pne2/index.php?action=tous), you can filter names if everything's good. Then click on the top left panel and click something, notice what happens in the inspector...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: May I recommend if you are to develop using jQuery mobile to build your application around its functionality rather than trying to override its functionality.

Comment: It's difficult to see what your problem is without a clearer example. But if your problem is duplicate DOM IDs, why not either remove and replace the container instead of appending to it (which is what I'm assuming you're doing but I can't see where from that link) or use classes instead of IDs?

Comment: jQuery is very well able to remove elements from the DOM tree. You just have to do it...

Comment: @moopet Actually I'm not sure if it's duplicate id's. I'm not appending anything, ajax does it on its own simply by clicking a link. If you want a clearer example go [here](https://partyneverends.noho.st/pne2/index.php?action=presents) then from the panel click on "Tous". The content from tous is loaded in a new page div and the search doesn't work anymore. Thanks!

Comment: @arkascha How would I go about it ? Create a javascript function that deletes the previous elements when I click on a link ? Thank you

Comment: @apokryfos I'm not sure I understand. I'm using the stuff I found on the [official demo](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/listview/) and I was surprised that the default ajax loading is breaking the dynamic elements. I guess it is not the same with php generated pages.

Comment: Check http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/intro/#AjaxNavigationTransitions in short: document.ready is basically meaningless in jQuery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have missed enclosing the selector within qoutes...

**your jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //bind a listener to "click" event on links with class "markviewed"
   $('a.ui-btn-present').click(function(event) {
    $('ul.listlist').listview('refresh');
```

**$(#pageone).remove();  //<-- selector should be within quotes**

```
// get ids from clicked <a>
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
   $(this).attr({
            "class" : "ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext-ok ui-icon-check ui-btn-a"
        });
```

Comment: change it to `$('#pageone').remove(); //<-- selector should be within quotes`

Comment: Thanks! I'm still a newbie in javascript but I found the solution for my real problem, thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

After much more research I wasn't looking in the right direction: the problem was that the listview had to be refreshed. So I created a new function

```
<script>
function refreshlist() {
    $('.listlist').listview("refresh");
    $('#pageone').remove();    
};
</script>
```

And then I added `onclick= "refreshlist()"`to all my links and now it works.